Can I use my encrypted WD external HD on Ubuntu?
My WD external HD is encrypted with WD software utilities which is available only for MAC and Windows.. I wonder if any alternative solution exists (Hardware encryption only pls not veracrypt)
for Linux in general.. I also need my drive to be cross compatible with Windows.. I cant be SOOL , this is such a basic thing..

This seems like a hardware question for WD.

not the best solution, but if you will use it primarily on Windows, maybe use Bitlocker (software encryption), and use dislocker on Linux

Ask Western Digital for Linux support. Also, can you find details of the encryption algorithm?  Unless WD releases the info, you ARE SOOL.

I would trust Veracrypt far more than some random software solution from Western Digital. They have a poor track record.
